# Byte Buddy not preserving return value when .andThen used

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am trying to use Byte Buddy to execute some additional logic when a method is done. Here is the sample code:

```
    T proxyClient = JAXRSClientFactory.fromClient(client, classType, true);
    this.configureHttpConduit(conduit, invocationTimeout);

    Class buddy = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(classType)
        .method(ElementMatchers.isAnnotatedWith(Path.class))
        .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(proxyClient)
            .andThen(MethodCall.run(new CloseConnection())))
        .make()
        .load(this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            Default.INJECTION)
        .getLoaded();

    return (T) buddy.newInstance();

  static class CloseConnection implements Runnable {
    void close() {
      System.out.println("close connection called");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      close();
    }
  }
```

When I chain the delegation with the .andThen call, the original caller to this instance loses the return values that was from the "proxyClient" object which it used to invoke a method call on it earlier. Am I using Byte Buddy wrong?

Basically I want to add some additional logic to the end of a method (inside the original method or adding another method call does not matter), but at the same time preserving the return value of the original method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. For every `Implementation` that you chain via `andThen`, Byte Buddy expects an empty stack for the next block. Thus, the last implementation is responsible for the return.

The idea of Byte Buddy is to put as much logic as possible into the interceptor. I would suggest to you to write your own interceptor that invokes the delegate and then invokes the close connection. This gives you also full control over the call conditions like closing in a finally block:

```
public class MyInterceptor<T> {

  final T proxyClient;

  @RuntimeType
  public Object intercept(@Origin Method method, 
                          @AllArguments Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    try {
      return method.invoke(proxyClient, args);
    } finally {
      // do your completion logic here
    }
  }
}
```

This can of course be improved in terms of performance. Have a look at the [@Pipe annotation](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/implementation/bind/annotation/Pipe.java) for that.